# C++ handles an uninitialized field in a strange way

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The sample below shows reading an uninitialized field a.i1 in two ways. The first call does not compile. However, calling a.donothing() that does not do anything, the original call compiles fine and prints the default value 0. Why is this inconsistency?

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015, the compiler output is as follows:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4700   uninitialized local variable 'a' used


class A {
  public:
   int i1;
   void donothing() {}
};
int main() {
  A a;

  cout << "main1: " << a.i1 << endl; // compile fails
  a.donothing();
  cout << "main2: " << a.i1 << endl; // prints 0 (default)
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reading uninitialized value is UB.

Comment: With `The first call does not compile` do you mean that there is a warning? Because the code compiles just fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d7d906f0d3f00ab

Comment: *The first call does not compile* -- And what is the exact compiler error message?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Community 2015, the compiler output is as follows; 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C4700 uninitialized local variable 'a' used

Comment: So you are engaging in undefined behaviour - what exactly do you expect? You really can't expect *anything*. The compiler can do whatever it pleases.

Comment: undefined behavior in your code. you have to initialize members before using them

Comment: Googling "C4700" gives lots of answers.

Comment: Why do you think that such behavior is strange?

Comment: @Jarod42: Unless it's an `unsigned char` (fun fact).

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is doing what it ought to do. You can fix it like this (as one solution out of many):

```
class A {
  public:
   A(int i = 0) : i1(i) {}
   int i1;
   void donothing() {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases a warning must be issued, at most. The fact that calling `donothing` cancels the error is a clear indication that this is a bug. You can report it at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/).

A simple workaround for this problem is to change the declaration to `A a{};`.

You can test your code on different compilers at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/).

**[EDIT]** The warning message `C4700` is treated as an error if *Security Development Lifecycle* is turned on (`/sdl`).

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the compiler, the compiler should supply a default constructor that will initialize your members with a default value. But this behavior is not dependable.  Since C++11 you can say ClassName()=default;  The best practice is to prove your own default constructor.

Your code never had any compiler errors with g++ 5.4.0

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
   public:
      //A() : i1(0) { } // compiler will provide this if you don't write anything
      // since C++ 11 you can also say A() = default;
      A() = default;
      int i1;
      void donothing() {} 
      void writeMember() const { cout << "i1 value: " << i1 << endl; }
};            

// better provide a signature for the main function
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   A a;

   a.writeMember();
   cout << "main1: " << a.i1 << endl; // compile fails
   a.donothing();
   cout << "main2: " << a.i1 << endl; // prints 0 (default)
   return 0; 
}
```

To compile the above code stored in testclass.cpp

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o testclass testclass.cpp
```

By using the C++11 default I got

```
i1 value: 4196976
main1: 4196976
main2: 4196976
```

If you comment out A()=default; this will rely on the compiler provided initializer, or the compiler may be lazy and not doing anything for performance reasons.  You get

```
i1 value: 4196944
main1: 4196944
main2: 4196944
```

If you uncomment the line after public: you should consistently get 0

This illustrates the importance of adhering to good conventions of alway provide your own default constructor.  The compiler maybe doing the right thing by not assigning any particular value to your member because you may assign another value in the next operation. This can save one operation.  The member will be simply allocated on the stack, in that case the member got a random value. If you run this code on a different computer you will for sure get a different value.

Comment: *"Depends on the compiler, the compiler should supply a default constructor that will initialize your members with a default value."* - No. *"compiler will provide this if you don't write anything"* - Again, no. That's a dangeorus misconception. *"better provide a signature for the main function"* - No, `int main()` is perfectly fine if you don't read any command-line arguments.

Comment: *"good conventions of alway provide your own default constructor"* - Only if the data members don't know how to correctly initialise themselves. It's pointless if you have e.g. only `std::string` members and would only manually default-initialise them anyway.

Comment: Hackl I agree with you, in cases where you don't know what to do.  In most my projects if I know what is the default value I will give it one.  When I was designing a simple Interval calss of two positive numbers, I initialize it to (-1,-1) to signify this is a null value.